# Problem with connecting microbit to the microbit python editor

Tags: python, micropython, bbc-microbit

I tried to connect to my microbit, which is plugged into my computer on the micropython editor - https://python.microbit.org/v/2.

Whenever I connect, it shows an error that access denied. I tried closing tabs and replugging my microbit, but nothing happens. But, I am able to connect to the makecode website.

What should I do to solve the problem?

Comment: Does the dev console have some more info? What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

That can happen if you have MakeCode opened in a different tab/window/browser, you should be able to connect with the Python Editor if you close the MakeCode tab.

Comment: It's not open but still I am not able to connect.